# Unable to compile sources with ta-lib

Tags: c, finance

I'm trying to use the ta-lib (http://ta-lib.org/) C API in my C application.
I downloaded the sources of ta-lib, installed them on my system using make install. Library compiled successfully and I have its binaries in `/usr/local/lib/`.
Then I compile my app as suggested on ta-lib site:

```
$ gcc -L/usr/local/lib -lta-lib -o tlc talib_test.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lta-lib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

OS: I'm using Ubuntu 9.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance that you have installed a 32-bit copy of `libta-lib.so` and are compiling a 64-bit test program, or vice versa?  That is, could you have a mismatch in the type of library?

Failing that, have you looked at `/usr/local/lib` to check that you have `libta-lib.so` in there?  Or could it be that the library is actually called `libta.so` or something like that, so you need to specify `-lta` on the command line?

---

On my Mac, the library was installed as shown (after a couple of minutes compilation):

```
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libta_lib.lai /usr/gnu64/lib/libta_lib.la
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libta_lib.a /usr/gnu64/lib/libta_lib.a
```

This would require `-lta_lib` with an underscore instead of `-lta-lib` with a dash.

Comment: Using `-lta_lib` instead of `-lta-lib` like the docs suggest worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Where is libta-lib.a ?  The error message suggests the linker cant find the library.